# DirectX Transparent textures - Making plants look good

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, alpha-transparency

I've recently started learning DirectX programming in C++, I have some experience of graphical programming in other languages however I am new to the DirectX scene.

Anyway, I wanted to ask a question about transparent textures. So far I've always used alpha testing as that has reached my needs, however I've recently began to wonder how "proper" game engines manage to render such good looking semi-transparent textures for things like plants and trees which have smooth transparency.

As everytime I've used alpha testing, the texutres have ended up looking blocky and just plain bad. I'd love to be able to have smooth, semi-transparent textures which draw as I would expect.

My guess as to how this works would be to execute render calls in order, starting with things that are far away from the camera and moving closer, However, I can't really see how this works for pre-made models, for example if you had a tree model where the leaves and trunk shared a model, how to guarantee that the back leaves would draw, and the trunks would draw correctly over the leaves, and that the front leaves would look correct over the trunk.

I had tried that method above and had also disabled z buffering for the transparent objects such as smoke particles, and it sort of worked, but looked messy and the effect appeared different depending on the viewing angle. So that didn't seem ideal.

So, in short, what methods do "proper" games use to correctly draw smooth alpha textures (which have a range of alpha values) into a 3D scene for things like foliage.

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: The problem you experience when disabling z-buffering has to do with end color being dependent on draw order. One way is to sort all your transparent objects from farthest to nearest, and draw in that order. There are a few articles on this page: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-10-transparency/ which deal with the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ordered transparency is accomplished most basically using the [painters algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter's_algorithm).

The painter's algorithm falls apart where an object needs to be drawn both in front of and behind another object, or where a single object has multiple sub components that are transparent. We can't easily sort sub-components of a mesh relative to each other.

While it doesn't solve the problems z-buffer allows us to optimize rendering. Most games use this slightly more complex algorithm as the basis of their rendering.

1. Render all Opaque objects sorted by material state or front to back
   to avoid overdraw.
2. Render all Transparent objects sorted front to back.

Games use a variety of techniques in combination to avoid this problem.

Split models into non overlapping transparent sections. Often times this is done implicitly because a game's transparent objects will often use use different materials than the rest of the model. You can also split models with multiple layers of transparency in such a way that each new model's layers do not overlap. For example you could split a pine tree model radially into 5 sections.

This was more common in fixed function pipelines. Modern games simply try to avoid the problem.

Avoid semi-transparent parts in models. Use transparency only for anti-aliasing edges and where the transparent object can split the world cleanly into two separate groups of objects. (Windows or water planes for example). Splitting the world like this and rendering those chunks front to back allows our anti-aliased edges to be drawn without causing obvious cut-outs on other transparent objects. The edges themselves tend to look good even if they overlap as long as your alpha-test is set higher than ~30%.

Semi transparent objects are often rendered as particle effects. Grass and smoke are the most common examples. The point list for the effect or group of grass objects is sorted each frame. This is a much simpler problem than sorting arbitrary sub meshes. Many outdoor games have complex grass and foliage instancing systems. These allow them to render individual leaves, and blades properly sorted and avoid most of the rendering overhead of doing it in this fashion but they strictly limit the types of objects.

Many effects can be done in an order independent way using additive and subtraction blending rather than alpha blending.

There are a couple easy options if your smooth edges are still unacceptable. You can dither any parts of the model below 75% transparency. Or you can have the hardware do it for you without visible artifacts by using coverage-to-alpha. This causes the multisampling hardware to dither the edges in the overdrawn samples. It won't give you a smooth gradient but the 4-16 levels of alpha are perfectly acceptable for anti-aliasing edges and free if you already intend to use MSAA.

There are a lot of caveats and special cases. If you have water you will probably need to render any semi-transparent objects that intersect the water twice using a stencil or depth test.

Moving the camera in and out of transparent objects is always problematic.

It is nearly impossible to render a complex semi-transparent object. Like an x-ray view of a building or a ghost. Many games simply render this type of object as additive. But with modern hardware a variety of more complex schemes are possible.

**More complex schemes**

Depth Peeling is a method of rendering where you render multiple passes with different Z-clipping planes to composite the scene from back to front regardless of order or what object contains the alpha. It is less expensive than you would expect because many objects render to only one or two slices. But it is not perfect and many game developers find it too costly.

There are many other varieties of [Order Independent Transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-independent_transparency). With a modern GPU and compute we can render in a single pass to a buffer where each pixel is a stack of possible slices. We can then sort the stack and blend these slices in a post process, and only incur the performance penalty when there are layers of transparency on a pixel.

OIT is still mostly only used in special cases like 2.5D games (such as little Big Planet). But I believe that it may eventually become a core tool in game programming.